# Migrate from two string yes/no variable to a single boolean variable in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, ruby-on-rails-5.1

The question is about rails database migration.

The current database contains two entries for a supposedly boolean variable as in the database scheme as follows:

```
create_table "table_name", force: :cascade do |t|
    ... 

    t.string "yes_boolvar"
    t.string "no_boolvar"
    ...

end
```

I need to convert it to one single boolean variable as following:

```
    t.boolean "boolvar"
```

I considered about renaming the 'yes_boolvar', changing its type from string to boolean, and then removing 'no_boolvar' column, based on some readings, like the following:

```
 t.rename :yes_boolvar,
          :boolvar
 t.change :boolvar,
          :boolean
 t.remove :no_boolvar
```

However, this will only consider the truth value of 'yes_*' and not 'no_*' while copying the value of the variable. Is there a way to successfully migrate the var so that the truth (or nil) values of the both the vars are taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your app.

If no one can update those values (i.e. it is not a field in a user profile), then you can:

1. make a database dump
2. run your migration
3. execute a code that will fill `boolvar`

Another solution is to migrate data in 3 steps:

1. first migration renames column
2. second migration migrates data
3. third migration removes `no_boolvar` column

I guess it is possible to merge the first two actions into a single migration (but I prefer to keep them separated).

Answer (score 0):

I recommends you to handle with 3 migrations.
For first, create a migration adding a `boolean: :boolvar`

```
class AddBoolvarToTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :table, :boolvar, :boolean
  end

  def down
    remove_column :table, :boolvar  
  end
end
```

After, create a new migration to handle data:

```
class RepopulateBooleanValues < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    YourClass.all.each do |record|
      # put the logic here like:
      record.boolvar = record.yes_boolvar == 'true' 
      # or 
      record.boolvar = record.not_boolvar == 'false'
      # I'am not sure whats the content of yes_boolvar and not_boolvar, elaborate the logic here
      record.save
    end
  end
end
```

To finish it, just create a new migration removing `yes_boolvar` and `no_boolvar`.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly the migration I'd write (I didn't run the code, but it should work):

```
# This ensures the migration to work
# regardless the customizations on your original model
class TempModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'table_name'
end

class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    add_column :table_name, :boolvar, :boolean

    TempModel.reset_column_information
    TempModel.find_each do |record|
      # Decide some logic here about how to migrate values from yes_boolvar
      # and no_boolvar columns to boolvar column
      boolvar_value = record.yes_boolvar || !record.no_boolvar
      record.update_column :boolvar, boolvar_value
    end

     remove_column :table_name, :yes_boolvar
     remove_column :table_name, :no_boolvar
  end

  def down
    add_column :table_name, :yes_boolvar, :string
    add_column :table_name, :no_boolvar, :string

    TempModel.reset_column_information
    TempModel.find_each do |record|
      # Decide some logic here about how to handle yes_boolvar
      # and no_boolvar values
      record.update_columns yes_boolvar: record.boolvar,
                            no_boolvar: !record.boolvar
    end

    remove_column :table_name, :boolvar
  end
end
```